# Convert text to float, when text comes in different formats

Tags: mysql

I want to store a text as a float. My problem is, that this text comes in different formats , and I cannot influence that. My TEXT column contains strings like

357000

218000.56

500.000.00

I don't have a problem converting the first two strings. I DO have a problem converting the last one, because the decimal mark is the same character as the thousands separator.

How should I deal with this problem? Is there an explicit conversion string-to-float using a format I can define?

EDIT: I forgot to say, that in the above cases, the last . (if there is any) is always the decimal separator if it is followed by a two digits number. So, '153.650' should convert to 153650 for example.

Comment: This is not an easy problem to solve if there are no constraints on the input format. Is `500.000.000` meant to represent 5.00000000 x 10^5 or 5 x 10^8? Typically, one uses ',' as the thousands separator and '.' for the decimal point or vice versa. Using the same character for both in the same number seems more like an error that must be corrected rather than worked around.

Comment: You are right. It is an user error, but I can not prevent it happen. I want to find a way to recognize the correct number.

Comment: Just a guess,you could insert in other table all strings with 2 dots or more,delete them and than convert them to what you need.I doubt there is a solution which will work on all formats.

Comment: Thanks, I see, there is no simple way to do that...thanks for the workaround hint, seems like I have to do something ugly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "EDIT: I forgot to say, that in the above cases, the last . (if there is any) is always the >decimal separator if it is followed by a two digits number. So, '153.650' should convert to >153650 for example."

There's your answer.

Check if the character at index (yourString.Length - 3) is one of your delimiters. If it is, then you have a decimal value; if not, you don't. Proceed to strip out all extraneous symbols and then re-insert your choice of decimal separator at the correct index.

Clean? No. But the situation stinks, TBH.

Comment: I know the situation stinks :) Appreciate your input anyway, I will figure out something like you proposed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
CONVERT(
REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '.', ''), ',', '.'), 
DECIMAL(10,2))
```

this will replace . and, from your string and will convert it into decimal (10,2).
According To Your

```
SELECT 
  IF(
    LENGTH(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX('351.000', '.', - 1)
    ) >= "3",
    CONVERT(
      REPLACE("351.000", ".", ''),
      DECIMAL (10, 2)
    ),
    CONVERT(
      CONCAT(
    REPLACE(
      LEFT(
        '351.000',
        LENGTH("351.000") - LOCATE('.', REVERSE("351.000"))
      ),
      '.',
      ''
    ),
    CONCAT(
      ".",
      SUBSTRING_INDEX('351.000', '.', - 1)
    )
      ),
      DECIMAL (10, 2)
    )
  )
```

I have tried for

1234.56 gives 1234.56

1234.000.00 gives 1234000.00

and 1234.000 gives 1234000

but it is not a good way to do so much in mysql query. you should handle it in programming part

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your code results in 35184250.00 when i want to convert '351842.50'. It should result to 351842.50 in this case.

Comment: but if there are two decimal then which one will be considered .then i will change my fucntion

Comment: The problem is, there can be strings like '1.400.000.00', '100.000', '100.000.23' and '100000.23'. The results should be: 1400000, 100000,100000.23 and 100000.23

Answer (score 0):

Correct the data before giving them to SQL - a programming language is simpler, for instance using regular expression replace.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\D(\\d\\d\\d)", "$1").replaceFirst("\\D". ".");
```

(Which does not consider signs!)
It first removes non-digits followed by three digits, and then make a period out of the first remaining non-digit. Can be done smarter.

The above is Java, but regex exists in all sensible programming languages.

Comment: Thanks...I only can use Javascript, and it seems there the function replaceAll and replaceFirst does not exist :(

Comment: JavaScript: `s = s.replace(/\\D(\\d\\d\\d/g, '$1').replace(/\\D/, '.');`

Comment: Sorry, was to hasty (in JS no double backslashes); a bit more exact: `s = s.replace(/[.,](...)/g, '$1').replace(/,/, '.');`

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7e9c1/32)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`TEXT` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`TEXT`)
VALUES
    ('357000'),
    ('218000.56'),
    ('500.000.00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CAST(concat(
       REPLACE(CASE WHEN substr(TEXT,-3,1) = "." THEN substr(TEXT,1,length(TEXT)-3)
            ELSE TEXT END,'.',''),
       CASE WHEN substr(TEXT,-3,1) = "." THEN right(TEXT,3) 
            ELSE '' END) AS decimal(12,2)
       ) AS Amount
FROM Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7e9c1/32/0)**:

```
|    AMOUNT |
|-----------|
|    357000 |
| 218000.56 |
|    500000 |
```